# Question on calculus of functions that take values in Banach Spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces

I've recently started a course on PDEs, and one of the first constructions we made was the following.

Say we have a PDE: $$F(t,x_1,\dots,x_n,u,u_t,u_{x_1},\dots,u_{x_n},\dots) = 0$$

with $u(t,x): \Bbb R\times \Bbb R^{n}\to\Bbb R$ being as smooth as necessary. For my question assume $n = 1$ for simplicity. Now we interpret $u(t,x$) as $u(t)(x)$ with $$\begin{align}u:\Bbb R& \to \mathcal C^h(\mathbb R)& \\
                       \quad \qquad\qquad t\mapsto &\quad\quad u(t):\Bbb R\to\Bbb R \\
                       & \quad\qquad x\mapsto u(t)(x) = u(t,x)\end{align}$$

(yes, I use the same $u$ for different functions, but I think which is which will be clear from context in the following).

Then, PDEs could be interpreted as $$u'(t) = H(u)$$ with $H :\mathcal C^h(\Bbb R)\to \mathcal C^h(\Bbb R)$, and the derivative of a function whose values are in $\mathcal C^h(\Bbb R)$ is defined with the usual difference quotient (and convergence in the $\mathcal C^h $ norm). This allowed for some developments on existence, uniqueness, etc.

My problem is that we didn't establish, or even mention the obviously desired correspondence: $$(u'(t))(x) = u_t(t,x)$$
What's more, we went through many deductions that involved passing to integral form, and here again, you obviously want $$\left (\int_a^b u(s)\, ds \right )(x) =\int_a^b u(s,x)\,ds$$

along with $u$ (with values in the function space) to be measurable in the first place (and with which measure??).

In summary, I feel that these sort of things should be established, if they are to help discuss PDEs, right? Please let me know if my question isn't clear. If it is, could you refer me to a book or other material that discusses this?

Comment: Section E.5 of the appendix to L. Evans, *Partial Differential Equations,* 2nd edition deals with spaces of Banach-valued functions. Unfortunately it's rather sparse at 2 pages long, but it points you to other references (by Folland, DeBenedito, and Yosida) that appear to treat them in more detail. Unfortunately I can't comment on those sources, having never read them.

Comment: Stupid question: What is $C^h(\Bbb R)$ ?

Comment: @SubSevn Shorthand for $\mathcal C^h(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$, the set of real valued functions of one real variable, that are $h$ ($\in\Bbb N$) times differentiable, with the $h^{\text{th}}$ derivative being continuous.